# two-way crosstabulate of multiple columns

Tags: r, associations, correlation, crosstab

I have data on patient diagnosis. There are 13 columns, each with different disease type, and they all store binary values (0- no disease, 1-disease present).
I want to see the coocurrence of the diseases, i.e. to see how many times disease type 1 exists in a patient who also has disease type2.
My data (simplified):

```
ID <- sample(10:50, 20)
type1 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)
type2 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)
type3 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)
type4 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)
type5 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)
type6 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = T)

data <- cbind.data.frame(ID, type1, type2, type3, type4, type5, type6)
```

I am looking for something similar to the output of cor(, that would give me **counts** rather than **frequency/correlation measure**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
data_matrix <- as.matrix(data[, 2:ncol(data)])
cooccurrence <- crossprod(data_matrix)
diag(cooccurrence) <- 0
```

This is a symmetric matrix. Take only the upper or lower triangle.